# Get a Power BI access token after logged into Azure AD

Tags: azure, api, rest, powerbi

I have code that logs me into Azure AD, but I cant' figure out how to get the access token to call the REST API's or PowerBI

Comment: You didn't showed your code, nor said what language or library is used. The access token is taken by calling some of the [AcquireToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is the sample code to get access token for Power BI REST API.

```
//The client id that Azure AD created when you registered your client app.
string clientID = "{Client_ID}";

//RedirectUri you used when you register your app.
//For a client app, a redirect uri gives Azure AD more details on the application that it will authenticate.
// You can use this redirect uri for your client app
string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";

//Resource Uri for Power BI API
string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

//OAuth2 authority Uri
string authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";

// AcquireToken will acquire an Azure access token
// Call AcquireToken to get an Azure token from Azure Active Directory token issuance endpoint
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).Result.AccessToken;

Console.WriteLine(token);
```

For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/walkthrough-push-data-get-token).